# simple Search in cakephp 2.0

Tags: php, cakephp, search

I am trying to build a simple phonebook in cakephp 2.0 that stores & retrieves information.

currently i have a table named contacts, with the following fields in it. 
 - Name
 - Phone no.
 - email
 - Location

I would like to integrate a simple search feature that lists contacts matching to the query. since its a very basic simple app, I wanna keep this as simple as possible.

any suggestions?

Comment: Is there something specific you're stuck on? It does sound like a basic `find()` query would do the trick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?php
$keyword=$this->params->query['keyword']; //get keyword from querystring//
//used simpme or condition with singe value checking
//replace ModelName with actual name of your Appmodel
$cond=array('OR'=>array("ModelName.phone LIKE '%$keyword%'","ModelName.name LIKE '%$keyword%'", "ModelName.email LIKE '%$keyword%'")  );

$list = $this->ModelName->find('all',array('conditions')=>$cond);


?>
```

Comment: This enables SQL injection attacks. Sanitize your input before using it as a query. Better use: `$keyword = '%'.$this->params->query['keyword'].'%';` and `array('ModelName.phone LIKE' => $keyword);`.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend to use a plugin like
https://github.com/dereuromark/search
to keep it DRY and simple.

it is a 3-liner you need to add to the action
and only a few lines of configuration in the model as well as a small form in the view.
that's it.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to revive a answered question, I solved this bit the same way (sort of) and this works with CakePHP 2.3.5

```
$options = array(
'conditions' => array(
    'OR' => array(
        'Listing.description LIKE' => '%'. $keyword . '%',
        'Listing.title LIKE' => '%'. $keyword . '%'
        )
    )
);
$list = $this->Listing->find('all', $options);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the find() method for search queries .. for more details .. visit the link below

[Retrieving data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just create a simple search function and use conditions array for matching your search fields and use that array in either find a function or paginate function like [explain in this example.](http://codingkala.com/cakephp-search-with-pagination/)

Comment: It's best to post the relevant information from a link as while a link is useful if it dies then so does your post. Cheers